# WCF Service + Entity Framework Class Customization

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, serialization

I'm currently developing a project with SQL Server + Entity Framework + WCF service.

The main goal is to map a SQL Server database to class objects with Entity Framework, customize them and build a WCF service that uses this objects.

So the first part is done. I've created the database and mapped the object with Entity Framework.

For the customization part of the process, what I've done was to implement new objects that inherit from the Entity Framework created objects in order to provide them custom functionality. So far so good.

When I try to send one of the objects created with Entity Framework from the WCF service to a WCF client all works OK, but when I do the same with my own object (that inherits from the EF object) it gives me an error:

> Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.

If I try to include `[DataContract]` on my custom class, it says that I should do the same with the base class (created by EF). The point is: I can't change the EF classes because I will lose the changes on a next update.

Can any body point me in the right direction?

Best regards,
José Pedro Silva

Comment: Could you show the code how you have implemented the custom class?

Comment: You want to add a partial class definition with the appropriate attributes on it.